# HTML5 data-* attribute rules?

Tags: html

I was wondering if you can have a data-* attribute that is just `data-`? or just `data`?

What are the rules here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `data-*` attribute rules are specified in [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).

From the spec:

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string `"data-"`, has **at least one character after the hyphen**, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

Note that it also restricts the usage to lower case, however another note applies:

> All attributes on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase letters doesn't affect such documents

Comment: Link broken for me. Here's one that worked http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute